# Auto Hot keys Like VBA Script

Tags: vba, automation, autohotkey

Ok, so on my work computer I can not download AutoHotKeys. I have some repetitive tasks that just involve clicking and very minor keyboard inputs. I found a code on line ill put below that acts as a mouse mover, and id like to add some functionality to this but so new to coding I am lost (but trying to learn).  The code below moves the mouse and clicks once, works even if I minimize the excel doc and am working in program. So What I am trying to do is be able to make a list of commands for it to follow like AHK. This script already shows me mouse location in pixels, so I can write down the pixel, add it to the sheet, add a sleep xxxx for the amount of time to sleep and then move and click on the next one. This would save me 20 minutes twice a day and I am determined to make it work.  So I want to add to this script or make a new one, and just make it move, click, send text,  and sleep.

```
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10

Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Public Type POINTAPI
x As Long
y As Long
End Type

Sub MouseMove()

Dim lngCurPos As POINTAPI
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

StartTime = Timer
StartTime1 = Timer
GetCursorPos lngCurPos
x2 = lngCurPos.x
y2 = lngCurPos.y
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B6").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Cursor Position"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "Time Elapsed"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = "Seconds Elapsed"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = "Time Remaining"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value = "Times Activated"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value = "Total Run Time"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value = "Time to Activate"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B7").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 21
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 15
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value = "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value = "12:01:00 AM"
End If
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

SecondsToActivate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value
SecondsToActivate = Hour(SecondsToActivate) * 3600 + Minute(SecondsToActivate) * 60 + Second(SecondsToActivate)

counter = 0

Do

DoEvents

GetCursorPos lngCurPos
x1 = lngCurPos.x
y1 = lngCurPos.y

If x1 <> x2 Or y1 <> y2 Then
    StartTime = Timer
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MinutesElapsed = Format(((Timer - StartTime) - 0.5) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "X: " & lngCurPos.x & " Y: " & lngCurPos.y
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = MinutesElapsed
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = SecondsElapsed
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value = Format(((SecondsToActivate - SecondsElapsed) + 0.5) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value = counter
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value = Format(((Timer - StartTime1) - 0.5) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

If SecondsElapsed < SecondsToActivate * 0.7 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
ElseIf SecondsElapsed >= SecondsToActivate * 0.7 And SecondsElapsed < SecondsToActivate * 0.8 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
ElseIf SecondsElapsed >= SecondsToActivate * 0.8 And SecondsElapsed < SecondsToActivate * 0.9 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
ElseIf SecondsElapsed >= SecondsToActivate * 0.9 And SecondsElapsed < SecondsToActivate * 0.95 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ElseIf SecondsElapsed >= SecondsToActivate * 0.95 Then
    If SecondsElapsed Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf SecondsElapsed Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
End If

If SecondsElapsed >= SecondsToActivate Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    For i = 1 To 500
        For j = 1 To 100
            SetCursorPos x1 + j, y1
        Next j
        For j = 99 To 0 Step -1
            SetCursorPos x1 + j, y1
        Next j
    Next i
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&
    Sleep 100
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&
    Sleep 100
    SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
    Sleep 100
    SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
    Sleep 100
    StartTime = Timer
    counter = counter + 1
End If

GetCursorPos lngCurPos
x2 = lngCurPos.x
y2 = lngCurPos.y

Sleep 250

Loop

End Sub
```

So if anyone can help me modify this that would be great, Not looking for someone to make it for me but I'm trying to learn how to do this so any direction would be beneficial.

Comment: It's likely you can achieve your goal without moving the mouse or selecting cells. What sort of data do you need to enter? Is it always the same? If not where is it coming from? Where does the data go? Is it always the same place in the worksheet?

Comment: Its mainly clicking. I have a few reports I need to run and most of it is in a different program. I need to click on a drop down, click on a person, 3 more clicks to get to the right spot, click on the download button that downloads it to a different internal program, then once I do that for 10 people I go to the second program and can export it to excel, the problem is its a slow process and takes me 20 minutes of mindless clicking. But the buttons are always in the same place so if I had AHK I could set it up once with a script and walk away for 20 minutes.

Comment: I am happy to set the cursor position and click for each move, with a sleep in between. I just don't understand the coding well enough to add a new function to this, I can just write it once in VBA and never have to do it again.  I tried a few variations and all had errors.

Comment: Other options are: use AutoHotKey as a portable app (no install), or convert the AutoHotKey script to an .exe and run that (portable).